# Enable WiFi in Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have HP Pavilion x360 with Kali Linux 2020.3. It is showing "Device not ready" under Wi-Fi networks.

The output of `lshw -C network` is as follows -

```
  *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 36:f8:82:fa:33:a5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.7.0-kali1-amd64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:160 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4200000-b420ffff
```

Output of ifconfig is

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 184  bytes 11968 (11.6 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 184  bytes 11968 (11.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of iwconfig is

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

**Update**
Output of `rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rndis_host             20480  0
cdc_ether              24576  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 53248  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
cdc_acm                40960  0
fuse                  139264  3
binfmt_misc            24576  1
sunrpc                503808  1
nls_ascii              16384  1
nls_cp437              20480  1
vfat                   20480  1
fat                    86016  1 vfat
snd_sof_pci            20480  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    90112  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               126976  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
wl                   6467584  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             323584  0
kvm                   811008  1 kvm_intel
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
rtwpci                 28672  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
snd_soc_core          278528  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
rtw88                 548864  1 rtwpci
snd_hda_codec_generic    94208  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof
intel_cstate           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          57344  3
mac80211              905216  2 rtwpci,rtw88
intel_uncore          163840  0
btusb                  57344  0
uvcvideo              114688  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
btintel                32768  1 btusb
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
videobuf2_common       57344  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
efivars                20480  1 efi_pstore
snd_hda_codec         163840  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
bluetooth             688128  5 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,btusb
snd_hda_core          106496  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
joydev                 28672  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
videodev              266240  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
watchdog               28672  1 iTCO_wdt
serio_raw              20480  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
snd_pcm               131072  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
hid_sensor_accel_3d    20480  1
hid_sensor_rotation    20480  0
hid_sensor_incl_3d     20480  0
hid_sensor_magn_3d     20480  1
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
drbg                   28672  1
snd_timer              45056  1 snd_pcm
ansi_cprng             16384  0
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     20480  0
hid_sensor_trigger     20480  13 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
hid_sensor_iio_common    20480  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
sg                     36864  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
snd                   106496  16 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
hid_multitouch         32768  0
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  5 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
soundcore              16384  1 snd
industrialio           94208  10 industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_incl_3d,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation
processor_thermal_device    20480  0
mei_me                 45056  0
intel_rapl_common      32768  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
tpm_crb                20480  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           28672  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    73728  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
mei                   122880  1 mei_me
ac                     16384  0
soc_button_array       20480  0
rng_core               16384  1 tpm
int3400_thermal        20480  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
acpi_tad               16384  0
intel_hid              24576  0
hp_accel               28672  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
acpi_pad               28672  0
lis3lv02d              28672  1 hp_accel
evdev                  28672  21
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
nvidia_drm             57344  2
nvidia_modeset       1187840  2 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19722240  72 nvidia_modeset
loop                   40960  0
8192eu               1581056  0
cfg80211              872448  4 wl,8192eu,mac80211,rtw88
rfkill                 28672  4 hp_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
efivarfs               16384  1
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                53248  2
ext4                  778240  1
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  139264  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
hid_sensor_custom      28672  0
hid_sensor_hub         24576  8 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_iio_common,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_custom
intel_ishtp_hid        28672  0
sd_mod                 57344  4
hid_generic            16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    24576  1 i2c_designware_platform
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  2
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
i915                 2596864  17
ahci                   40960  3
nvme                   49152  0
libahci                45056  1 ahci
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
nvme_core             110592  1 nvme
t10_pi                 16384  2 sd_mod,nvme_core
aesni_intel           368640  0
drm_kms_helper        249856  2 nvidia_drm,i915
libata                286720  2 libahci,ahci
xhci_pci               20480  0
libaes                 16384  2 bluetooth,aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cec                    61440  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
crc_t10dif             20480  1 t10_pi
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
xhci_hcd              290816  1 xhci_pci
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
sdhci_pci              57344  0
crct10dif_generic      16384  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
scsi_mod              258048  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
cqhci                  32768  1 sdhci_pci
crct10dif_common       16384  3 crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif,crct10dif_pclmul
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
usbcore               315392  9 8192eu,xhci_hcd,usbnet,cdc_acm,rndis_host,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci,cdc_ether
sdhci                  73728  1 sdhci_pci
idma64                 20480  0
intel_ish_ipc          28672  0
i2c_hid                32768  0
drm                   606208  11 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
mmc_core              184320  3 sdhci,cqhci,sdhci_pci
mfd_core               20480  2 hid_sensor_hub,intel_lpss
intel_ishtp            61440  2 intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc
usb_common             16384  3 xhci_hcd,usbcore,uvcvideo
hid                   147456  5 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
battery                20480  0
wmi                    36864  3 hp_wmi,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof
video                  53248  1 i915
button                 24576  0
```

Comment: please update the question with the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Please see I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If there is one, verify that the hardware switch for the Wi-Fi adapter on your laptop is set to the on position.

Check which driver Kali is trying to use with your adapter, the correct one is the RTW88 driver. It seems to be a common problem surrounding the RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter where the incorrect driver is loaded (if the wrong one is being used, you will have to blacklist the module by adding it to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, then load the correct one).

To check if you are using the RTW88 modules look in the output of `lsmod` you should see some of the following:

```
rtw_8723de 
rtw_8723d 
rtw_8822be 
rtw_8822b 
rtw_8822ce 
rtw_8822c 
rtw_core 
rtw_pci
```

If your version of Kali doesn't ship with the RTW88 module you may have to install it yourself.

Comment: I can see rtwpci and rtw88 in lsmod output.

Comment: Sounds like it is still being hardware blocked somehow, perhaps in the bios settings, or there may be a conflicting module loaded. Post the output of your `lsmod`

Comment: There's no option to block that in the BIOS. I have updated the output of lsmod.

Comment: Have you tried just using it? Test with something like `ip link set wlan0 up` and `iw dev wlan0 scan`

Comment: Yes, the first one gives 'RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument' and the second one gives 'command failed: Network is down (-100)'.

Comment: Shall I try reinstalling it??

Comment: I would say the problem is due to a hard-block, sometimes people have resolved this through BIOS resets, or just messing with the hardware switches, rfkill, and loading/reloading modules. I don't think reinstalling would fix it, but you never know until you try. I recommend you look into threads people have posted on hard-blocked Wi-Fi adapters all over the place such as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151098/wi-fi-doesnt-work-hard-blocked) and [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/wifi-hard-blocked-solution-4175592097/).